# How to enable EAR app log4j logging in TomEE 7.0.1 via log4j.xml?

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I am working on a Java EE application project which in general uses log4j (version 1.2.x) in modules and `.war` contexts.

Basically, the module setup via Maven is as follows:

```
| # app-bundle.ear
| - app-log4j-config.jar
    | - src/main/resources/log4j.xml
| - app-backend-module.jar (ejb-module)
| - app-web-ui-module.war
| - app-web-service-module.war
```

So I only have exactly one `log4j.xml` for the whole EAR app bundle.

Given a TomEE 7.0.x application server environment, I need to know, which steps are necessary to only log the application specific log messages (as configured via `log4j.xml`) but **not** the messages produced by the application server.

E.g. startup and shutdown messages should go to `catalina.out` but all log output from different backend or web modules (see above) should be printed / logged as specified by my log4j configuration.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to adapt the default `conf/system.properties` of the TomEE in any way? If so, what exactly needs to be added/edited?
2. Where do I put `log4j-<version>.jar`:  in *(a)* `lib` of the TomEE or *(b)* withing the apps folder of my EAR bundle?

What I have tried so far:

- Both `log4j.xml` and `log4j-<version>.jar` in `lib` of TomEE installation -> no success
- Both `app-log4j-config.jar` and `log4j-<version>.jar` bundled with the EAR -> no success
- Extracted `log4j.xml` in the `apps/project` together with bundled `log4j-<version>.jar` -> no success

Any help would be very welcomed.

EDIT: I am using a TomEE 7.0.1 in the PLUS variant.

EDIT-2: The `ear` is generated via Maven as followed:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-log4j-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-backend-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-web-ui-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>de.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>app-web-service-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- This dependency will be provided globally in the TomEE deployment -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>app-bundle</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
            <!-- configuring the ear plugin -->
            <configuration>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>de.myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>app-web-service-module</artifactId>
                    </webModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>de.myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>app-web-ui-module</artifactId>                         
                    </webModule>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>de.myapp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>app-backend-module</artifactId>
                    </ejbModule>                        
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The `log4j.xml` is this:

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
               value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}(%L): %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="DEBUGFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="file" value="logs/app-bundle-DEBUG.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}(%L): %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="debug"/>
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="info"/>
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>

<appender name="INFOFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="file" value="logs/app-bundle-INFO.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}(%L): %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="info"/>
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>

<appender name="WARNFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="file" value="logs/app-bundle-WARN.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}(%L): %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="warn"/>
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>

<appender name="ERRORFILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <param name="file" value="logs/app-bundle-ERROR.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}(%L): %m%n"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="error"/>
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelMatchFilter">
        <param name="LevelToMatch" value="fatal"/>
    </filter>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
</appender>

<logger name="de.myapp">
    <level value="INFO"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <!--
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    -->
    <appender-ref ref="ERRORFILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="WARNFILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="INFOFILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="DEBUGFILE"/>
</root>
```

EDIT-3: I try to build a skinny war file via Maven to build the mentioned `lib` directory via:

```
  <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
  <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
```

This does not succeed either.

EDIT-4: I have added the `sl4j-api.jar` to the EAR bundle via

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
   <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<jarModule>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
</jarModule>
```

On TomEE startup the files are created as expected in the `logs` directory. However, log-output still goes into `catalina.out` and not in the specified files.

EDIT-5: I did not properly rebuild the project via Maven. Finally, **adding** the `sl4j-api.jar` to the **EAR bundle module** is the solution to the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed related to the missing `slf4j-api` in the ´.ear´ bundle as suggested.

To trace down the issue I have created an [Github Sample](https://github.com/rzo1/log4j-ear-tomee-sample), which is an example of how integrate `slf4j` with TomEE in an `ear` context.

You need to ensure:

1. `slf4j-*` and custom implementation needs to be bundled as `jar` module in the `ear`
2. shared logger configuration needs to be provided in an own module, which is bundled as `jar` module in the `ear`

Hope this helps someone, who experience the same issues.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should put log4j* in lib part of the ear. What exactly doesnt work with this setup?

edit: also ensure you add slf4j-api along slf4j- if you provide your own impl of slf4j otherwise it will use the container one

Comment: I just added the Maven configuration, which is used to bundle the EAR. In my understanding, the log4j* stuff is put in the correct section? We do not see any kind of log output in the specific destinations... instead, everything is written to catalina.out

Comment: if you expect to use slf4j then you need to provide *in the ear* slf4h-api as well otherwise you end up using container one with its default binding (slf4j-jdk14) which uses JULi (conf/logging.properties)

Comment: @rmannibucau could you edit your answer with the information from your last comment? that seems valuable/important information.

Comment: I edited the question. The slf4j-api is now added to the EAR bundle. Files are created in the log directory, but still no log-output - everything runs to catalina.out

Comment: I have to correct myself. I added the slf4-api to the EAR bundle, did a proper maven rebuild and finally it is working. Thanks for your important hints!